# Efficiently replace &#x27; characters in a string

Tags: swift

I have a string that contains mulitple unicode hex characters - how can I efficiently replace all of these references with their character, e.g.

`"David&#x27;s car is green"`

becomes

`"David's car is green"`

Comment: I'm not sure if there's *one* way to efficiently replace these things - it requires some kind of mapping, which means I have a question for you. How (or why) are these unicode characters there? If it's because of how they are stored, the most efficient way may be to look at the source - database stored procedures, the input to the database, etc. If this is 100% local (and in Swift), why are they there at all?